# Freddie Mac purchased my mortgage, is this temporary?

Tags: united-states, mortgage

I just received a letter from Freddie Mac stating that they had purchased my one month old Pulte mortgage loan. I'm expected to keep making my payments to Pulte, my servicer, but am wondering if Freddie Mac is simply going to be selling my loan again to someone else? I've had mortgages in the past sold, but never to Freddie Mac, and I'm unaware how a GSE mortgage affects me, if at all.

Comment: This is best answered by your mortgage servicer.  Mortgages are bought and sold all the time. Small lenders don't have the capital to handle large portfolios over the lifetime of a mortgage (15 to 30 years in the USA), so they will routinely sell their mortgages to larger operations. Short term profit and ready cash now for more mortgages = more income for them.